# Cesium Chloride Density Gradient Centrifugation and Isotopes

Tags: bond, concentration, ions, ionic-compounds, isotope

In [Cesium Chloride Density Gradient Centrifugation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UvGCXtX5MAM&ab_channel=AllenGathman), as used by Meselson and Stahl, Cesium ions can be seen as strongly affected by centrifugation, so much so that they can overcome their ionic bonds with water.

Amidst an equilibrium of ionic bonds and centrifugation, cesium forms a gradient, with higher concentrations near the bottom of the tube, and vice versa.

If so, will there be an enrichment of trace Cesium-135 near the bottom of the centrifugation tube compared to the top? Cesium has the dominant isotope of Cesium-133.

I am exploring this question regarding my inquiry into isotope enrichment. I am asking this question because I can see the gradient is mass-dependent (Cl ions do not form such a gradient as they are much lighter), but have seen no results in the literature.

Comment: Regarding why I am investigating this over other dominant methods: yes, this method still requires high RPM and intensive energy usage. Yet, it has the clear advantage of only needing a couple of high-speed centrifuges. Maybe even just one.

Comment: IMHO, It would have *much* lower enrichment degree than centrifugation of gases. Cl- must form the same gradient as the average gradient of both Cs isotopes, otherwise coulombic force would overrule centrifugation.

Comment: @Poutnik Hello, thank you for your answer, and I apologize for the late reply due to exam season. I understand what you are saying: that the coulomb force would prevent the efficient creation of Cs gradients in the first place, and I think this fact will be useful in furthering this research. Once again, thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *ratio* of masses of <sup>135</sup>Cs to <sup>137</sup>Cs is smaller, by a factor of 5, than the ratio of masses of <sup>14</sup>N to  <sup>15</sup>N.

While what you suggest is *theoretically* possible, the thermal motion of water, which must be not much below 273 K, despite freezing point depression, would make separation of isotopes in liquid water unfeasible. It might actually be more energy efficient to use a mass spectrometer!

Sorry I couldn't put a better spin on that experiment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There is a crucial paper regarding this topic I want to discuss in private. Is there any way to do this on Stack Exchange?

Comment: @YoungJunLee, there *is* a chat section, https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=chemistry.stackexchange.com. However, I do not have expertise to be of help.